# Are users of an application API clients?

Tags: laravel, rest, api, laravel-passport

I am learning REST API server and client, and what I've understood so far is that clients are the application that consumes the API. For example, if my application is consuming a (public) API, my application is a client.

Now, I have recently started learning Laravel Passport to authenticate API clients. My confusion roots from here.

Through Passport, a user needs to be created and a 'client' token is associated with that user. And once logged in through the frontend of the app, the user communicates through a bearer token.

Shouldn't there be only one bearer token associated with an app? Isn't app the client? Why does the user need to create a client in Passport? Are users of my applications API clients too? Or is Passport for something entirely different?